# How portable is an STL typedef?

Tags: c++, stl

Is the following code portable?

```
template<typename In>
struct input_sequence_range : public pair<In,In> {
    input_sequence_range(In first, In last) : pair<In,In>(first, last) { }
};

template<typename Arr>
input_sequence_range<Arr*> iseq(Arr* a,
                                typename iterator_traits<Arr*>::difference_type n)
{
    return input_sequence_range<Arr*>(a, a + n);
}

template<typename Iter>
input_sequence_range<Iter> iseq(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    return input_sequence_range<Iter>(first, last);
}
```

Specifically I question the portability of overloading on std::iterator_traits<>::difference_type.  If it's typedeffed to, say, int* (as bizzare as that may be; I think the standard doesn't forbid this) then calling iseq() for an array of ints would be ambiguous.

What does the standard guarantee about iterator_traits<> typedefs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`difference_type` must be an integral type so `int*` is out.

Answer (score 0):

According to Josuttis, you *should* use the typedefs in order to be more flexible and properly generic. All of his examples that started off with something along the lines of "here's a fast way to do it" led to examples that were based on the STL typedefs.